# Some questions regarding maximal ideals in $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

It is said that the [integers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaximalIdeal.html) is a local ring and hence has a unique maximal ideal.

I have two doubts:

1. Why $(p)$ with $p$ prime is a maximal ideal? how can we know it is not possible to have $(p)\subsetneqq(q)\not=\mathbb{Z}$ for another prime $q$?
2. I doubt about the word unique maximal ideal. Since there are infinitely many primes, then there would be infinitely many maximal ideals generated by them, how can they be unique?

Thanks!

Comment: $\mathbb Z$ is *not* a local ring, what gave you this impression? You even proved yourself in your second bullet point that it has infinitely many maximal ideals.

Comment: The link you give is not optimally set out. Of course, $\mathbb Z$ is not a local ring. I'm not sure what the article you link to was trying to achieve exactly. It is confusing.

Comment: @nik. Oh yes, my mistake on that. But it is written in the link, although not explicitly, it gives the integers as an example of a local ring.

Comment: Looks like a bad copy and paste when somebody edited that page. I think the sentence beginning, "For instance,..." Was meant for the next paragraph.

Comment: If you are still in the market for local rings, though, the quotient $\Bbb Z/(p^n)$ is local for each prime $p$ and $n\geq 1$.

Comment: @user71346: Do you find any of the answers below acceptable? If so, you should accept one. If not, could you indicate what they are lacking?

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ be prime and suppose that $\langle p\rangle \subset I$ for some ideal $I$. As $\langle p\rangle \subset I$, there is $r \in I$ which is not a multiple of $p$, so $(p, r) = 1$ as $p$ is prime. Now note that $\langle p, r\rangle \subseteq I$, but as $(p, r) = 1$, there are $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ap + br = 1$, and therefore, for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, $(ak)p + (bk)r = k$. Hence, $\langle p, r\rangle = \{c_1p + c_2r \mid c_1, c_2 \in \mathbb{Z}\} = \mathbb{Z}$, and as $(p, r) \subseteq I$, we must have $I = \mathbb{Z}$. Therefore $\langle p\rangle$ is maximal.

As nik pointed out, $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a local ring, in fact there are infinitely many maximal ideals.

Answer (score 1):

Michael's answer is more general, but per you question in part (1), if $(p)\subsetneq (q)\neq \mathbb Z$ then since $p\in(p)$, then $p\in (q)$ and therefore $p$ must be a multiple if $q$. Is that possible of $p,q$ are distinct primes with $(p)\neq (q)$?

Answer (score 1):

$(p)$ is a maximal ideal   because $\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}$ is a field.